# Issue with strange faces around joints

Tags: faces

[image: Example]

I have been working on character modeling for the first time, having done static objects for some time, and have run into an issue. I created the hands and feet separately of the rest of the model, then connected them, but at the wrists and ankles I am getting odd distortion, as pictured. I've already eliminated N-Gons, converting them to tris, and flipped normals, but nothing seems to work to eliminate the distortion. I cannot identify why this is present, or how to remedy it. Any explanation or fixes?

Recalculating mormals fixes it locally, but just shifts the problem to another, nearby part of the model.

Comment: Are both instances of @Don the same user?

Answer (score 1):

Select everything in edit mode and hit Ctrl-N to recalculate the normals on your object. It looks like some normals are facing outward, others inward. That is why flipping the normals didn't fix your issue, as it flips them all, and you still had some facing in and some out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can help you more if you upload the file.(even a part of your polygons)

In the mean time, I would suggest you try several attemps.
(You don't have to do them in order. The order is irrelevant to the possibility)

1. Check the Normals
2. Remove doubles
3. Find a extra face or edge within your mesh
4. Switch the Shading to flat
5. Apply all modifiers if you have some

I will talk in them in detail.

**1. Check the Normals**

If trying "Recalculating" is the only thing you have done, try flipping the faces individulally. When you are in Edit mode, you can visualize the direction of the Normals in the [[Properties Region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/introduction.html#properties-region)] -> [Mesh Display] -> [Normals].

To filp a selected face, use the [Specials (W key)] ->[Filp Normals (F)]

**2. Remove doubles**
You might have several vertecies at the very same xyz coordinates. In this case, they can be removed by [Specials (W key)] ->[Remove Doubles (R)].

**3. Find a extra face or edge within your mesh**
You might be having an unwanted face like in the screen shot.

[image: example for 3]

I don't know the best way to remove this but there are some tips.

- Hiding vetecies with the H key may help you find the unwanted face.
- The [Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html) will be destorted around the extra face.

Note that this may happen with Edges too.

**4. Switch the Shading to flat**
The problem might be simply that the smooth shading seems unfamiliar. (Although I doubt it)
Set it to Flat.
See [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html) for more details.

**5. Apply all modifiers if you have some**
Maybe the reason is caused by some complex computing by the Modifiers.
If you have some try Applying them for a while.
Please be careful not to exceed to far that you cannot redo before applying.

Hope it helps.